# How to return h1 element from an API using React and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to display the title of a movie based on the movie searched for using movieDB's API, and using React and Axios. I have already tested the API in vanilla Javascript with fetch and `data['results'][0]['title']` gets the value I am trying to return as an H1 element. I had a submit button in vanilla javascript but I am now confused on where and how to implement it in react and not sure if that's what I need to do, or where to go from here based on tutorials I was watching, so far my code is:

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import Movielist from './components/Movielist'



function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="search" />
            <h1 id="title">title</h1>
            <Movielist />
        </div>

    )
}

export default App
```

Movielist.js (PROBLEM AREA)

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Movielist extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const API_KEY = '*********';
    const query = document.getElementById('search');
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {
        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

      })
  }

  render() {
    return (

    <h1>{this.state.title.value}</h1>

    )
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is what returns from the API in the browser with correct information and "Joker" as the query so I know that the API information is not the issue [image]

Comment: Why `title.value`?  Why not just `title`?

Comment: Just tried title by itself and now it is return "Null null" so that helped thank you. I just need to actually implement the search becuase I think it is automatically looking for the API without the information given

Comment: Yeah, I just switched ``` ${query}``` to ```joker``` in the code and it returns the title as soon as I refresh.

Comment: @zero298 how can I make the search bar return the query, do I make a new function or add ```componentDidMount()``` to an onClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search API should be called via a trigger and not on the component mount, that logic can be moved into a function and can be called as and when required.

You need

- A trigger(button) to fire the search event.
- An event handler that would be called on button click.

Since your input box is in App.js, it's a good idea to keep the button there as well. Also instead of getting the value of the input element via DOM, you can store it in state.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Movielist from "./components/Movielist";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: "",
    title: ''
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({searchText: e.target.value});
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const API_KEY = "*********";
    const query = this.state.searchText;
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`
      )
      .then(res => {
        const title = res.data["results"][0]["title"];
        this.setState({ title });
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="search" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
        <h1 id="title">title</h1>
        <Movielist title={this.state.title}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MovieList.js

```
import React from "react";

const MovieList = props => {
    return (<h1>{props.title}</h1>);
}

export default MovieList
```